# How to turn off cell brackets programmatically?

Tags: front-end, options, cells

From the documentation, it appears that executing

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellBracket -> False];`

in the current notebook, should immediately hide the cell brackets in the current notebook.

But nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you evaluate this from a cell in a notebook, it should work. If you're embedding the line in a plain-text code package, it's possible that `EvaluationNotebook[]` doesn't refer to the right thing. You could try `InputNotebook[]` as well. Or use `Notebooks[]` to find the right reference to the notebook you're trying to change.